# Wordpress wont find files

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I installed wordpress on  and I just want landing page to display, so I modified html templates and sliced them into *index.php*, *header.php*, *footer.php* and *sidebar.php*.

I put *style.css* in theme root, and there are some images in img and image directories, some additional css in css directory, and some javascript and jQuery in js directory.

My problem is that WordPress doesn't load any of those files. Only template, and when I click on one of them in source I got error **404**.

I tried to change permissions, I tried several ways of including those files, I tried anything I could find on google, and today is my deadline, I got project yesterday, so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You've got to go further back then. Maybe there's something wrong with your functions.php file. That's one of the first files that's loaded. So if something goes wrong there, the whole thing crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not added `<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>` in template where you have added js and css.. you must add in URL to get it work..

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/images/favicon.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/style.css">
```

**Edit :**
If above solution is not working please refer [Link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/changing-the-visible-url-path-to-css-js-files)

Comment: Thank you, this really is stupid mistake. Sorry. That worked. I linked my files with: similar function, but obviously wrong one. Thanks for help

Comment: It's ok!! Many times we got stuck in small stupid things!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look at your page. Seems like a simple mistake. Maybe your linked your files with src="js/myjsfile.js". The page redirects this to your root directory and searches there for the specific file. 
Use:

```
    src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/myjsfile.js"
```

The function adds the current template url to the path.